# How to fix ASUS random reboot

Tags: windows, laptop, hardware-failure, reboot

As the title is saying, I can't turn on my laptop while it's cold, I need to put it on a relatively hot radiator.

When I turn it on and it's cold there is only the "Turn on /turn off" button working and there is no other activity. I've already tried without the battery but nothing changed.

Moreover, my laptop i srandomly rebooting in-game and sometimes on desktop (using vlc, watching streams, surfing on internet ect.) but I guess it's an independent issue .

**What I've done :**

-fresh install on new hard disk --> same issue

-changed physical memory --> same issue

-stressed test memory, cpu and gpu --> no reboot, handly all of those tests perfectly

-tryed linux debian jessie, using propriatary graphic card drivers --> same issue

-activated blue screen errors, nothing changed, blue screen's not showing

-changed thermal paste from cpu and gpu --> no overheat

-checked windows system logs :

```
Log Name: System
Source: Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Event ID: 41
Level: Critical
Description:
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
```

Sometimes it's rebooting quickly, sometimes not. But when launching a game, it's rebooting directly, after 1 second.

**Something to know :**

Got NO reboot while laptop is UNPLUGGED. So I've ordered a new alimentation since for me it's the only possiblity for now (receiving this one tomorrow probably) --> received new power adapter and still got this problem.

Laptop specifications : it's an Asus ROG 75VW

```
Screen Size     17.3 inches
Screen Resolution   1920 x 1080
Max Screen Resolution   1920x1080
Processor   2.4 GHz Core i7-3630QM
RAM     12 GB DDR3
Memory Speed    1600 MHz
Hard Drive  750 GB mechanical_hard_drive
Graphics Coprocessor    Nvidia GTX 660M 2G GDDR5
Graphics Card Ram Size  2000 MB
Wireless Type   802.11bgn
Number of USB 3.0 Ports     4

Item model number   G75VW-AH71
Operating System    Windows 7 Integral Edition;
Processor Brand     Intel Core I7
Processor Count     4
Computer Memory Type    DDR3 SDRAM
Battery Type    Lithium-Ion (Li-Ion)
Power Source    Battery
Voltage     19 volts
```

Feel free to ask for more informations and thank you in advance if you've any suggestions .

Comment: Bad battery **and** power adapter is where I would start first.

Comment: With or without battery, it's the same. I'll have a look on power adapter.

Comment: Doesn't change anything... it's not power adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oven fixed all lol. 
Both issues were coming from GPU.

If you're encountering the same issue with random reboot (saw a lot of topic with no solutions) just put your graphic card 10min at 240°C in your oven. 
2nd card I'm repairing like this :-)
Bye.